# Can I reverse the consequences of eating something bad?

Tags: eating-habits

Can I reverse the consequences of eating something bad quickly by going to the gym.

e.g.  If I ate a brownie now, could I do an hour of cardio at the gym and then not 'put on that weight.

Or is there basically no stopping it.

Basically I want to every now and then cheat on my healthy living regime on Friday's.

Comment: Go ahead. Diet and nutrition are not immediate effect things. However, as your question stands, it's off topic for the site.

Comment: What is your fitness goal? And, what do you believe the consequences of eating that brownie are? Be as specific as you can be when you describe your goals and the consequences.

Comment: Are you currently following any exercise regimes at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking in terms of calories, then maybe - people are a little too eager to say it's all about calories consumed and calories burned, when in fact you can have a pretty wide range of results - but really bad food is food made with unhealthy ingredients, and that can't be reversed. If the ingredient list on the brownies is intelligible to you, you're probably fine, but if it has a bunch of compounds you don't recognise, the detriment to your health isn't related to (lack of) exercise.